# MariaDB LOAD DATA INFILE csv file not reading correctly

Tags: sql, csv, mariadb

File : /DNC/myphones.csv
CONTENTS:

Phone
 
5555555555
5555555556

SQL -
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/DNC/myphones.csv' INTO TABLE test
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

What Comes back back is several warnings and a few skips and one Record makes it into the table a record of 2174563487 - Most of these digits don't exist in the data. Where is this coming from?

csv was created in MSOUTLOOK 2010, Also tried the above with a "test" file written in nano of the same contents.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

UPDATE - Changing the Schema to a VARCHAR(255) Makes this work properly.
Could it be reading the CSV file contents as a string instead of as integer?
That would explain it not reading the values from the CSV but not where its getting the weird 217 #

Final Update. Since ill never perform mathematical operations on the phone number ive just decided to use a string instead. But thanks everyo e for your help

Comment: what is your "test" table schema?

Comment: Single Column "Phone" INT(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY

Comment: "/r/n" is another issues, answer updated.

Comment: Did you sanitize your data into integer?  A space, dash,etc will cause error and give you surprises. Otherwise, just store the field into VARCHAR and give it a unique ID.

Comment: Yes. The second test file i made with nano was just the phone numbers with no header. Id enter the # press enter, enter the other # then save

Comment: 2174563487 = 2**32-1, the largest signed value that can be stored in a 32-bit (4-byte) integer.

Answer (score 2):

First,  you schema only take integer, the header will cause server to spit error. 
If header not part of the data, why don't you skip it?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/DNC/myphones.csv' INTO TABLE test 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Seconds, incorrect line terminated. They are different for Windows"\r\n" and Linux "\r". However, "/" vs "\" is only apply for folder , not newline/tab/return character.

Comment: I will in the final draft. I'm going for a minimal coding approach in my testing so not typing that ignore 1 lines at the end for the 150+ times i've tried this saves a little bit of typing

Comment: Oops. The machine this is running on has no gui. I typed this in wrong when asking the question. will correct now.,

Comment: really, how much typing is omitted from the question?  don't tell me you ommit CSV field enclose and delimiter. ;-D

Comment: None from the question.... I didn't define the field enclose or the delimiter because it isn't technically delimited, there is only one field.